# MYSQL: Include Table Names in column headers after a Select *

Tags: mysql, select, join

I have a set of 15 tables with a large number of columns, I know how the joins work but many of the tables have similar column names.

For example:
Select * 
from table1
join table2 on table1.id = table2.id

I get back columns:
id|id|name|name

etc... I don't know which columns correspond to which tables. 
What I'd like to get returned is:
table1.id|table2.id|table1.name|table2.name

I realize that I could spell out the select statement like:
select table1.id 'table1.id', table2.id 'table2.id'

But there are hundreds of column names, and dozens of tables, so this would be impractical and it seems like something that should be easy to do.

Comment: where do you want this? in the mysql monitor (e.g. mysql command line), or in some app you're writing?

Comment: If you're involving "hundreds of columns and dozens of tables" in one query, there may be a bigger issue in play.

Comment: The database is adminned by a rather hostile SASS provider. I've got remote ODBC access that's very limited, anything more complicated that basic joins is locked down. And in fact, in a couple of months they are shutting off ODBC access as well so I'll lose all ability to report on this particular data. And yes we're dumping the provider but that sort of change takes time.

Comment: The data isn't... "data" in that it's the stuff we store in the application, its information about how different parts of the data interacts with itself. It's way too complex to explain here and I doubt you'd care. But I just want to dump it to a table and save it in a spreadsheet or something. So we have it after they shut off access. I could just save the tables individually but now I'm caught up in this academic exorcize of "I should be able to do this!" It just makes sense.